# Case insensitive varchar SQL Sybase

Tags: sql, sybase, case-sensitive, case-insensitive

I create a simple table `Company`, which has two fields - `ID` and `Name`.

```
CREATE TABLE Company (
ID int PRIMARY KEY,
Name VARCHAR(20)
)
```

By default in Sybase `VARCHAR` is case sensitive, but how may I declare a case insensitive `VARCHAR` field? 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What Sybase product are you running?

Answer (score 0):

Case sensitivity is actually a function of the Server Sort Order, and not specific to the VARCHAR datatype.  If the server is set to a case sensitive Sort Order, then values will be treated as case sensitive.

To find out your servers sort order issue the command **sp_helpsort** and look at the 'Sort Order' section.

To change the server sort order, the *sa* user can use the **sp_configure** command to change the default sort order.

If you don't have the option to change the server sort order, then I would suggest you look at using the *upper()* function in your querys.